# create new DataFrame resulted from processing N rows of other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to process each N rows of a DataFrame separately.
If my data has 15 row indexed from 0 to 14 I want to process rows from index 0 to 3 , 4 to 7, 8 to 11, 12 to 15 
for example let's say for each 4 rows I want the sum(A) and the mean(B)

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 | 9 |
| 2 | 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 | 9 |
| 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 0 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 7 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 6 |

The Resulted DataFrame should be

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 5 |
| 1 | 26 | 3.75 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 |

TLDR: how to let `DataFrame.apply` takes multiple rows instead of a single row at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with integer division by `4` by index:

```
#default RangeIndex
df = df.groupby(df.index // 4).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean'})

#any index
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 4).agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'mean'})
print (df)
    A     B
0  20  5.00
1  26  3.75
2   8  4.00
```

Comment: so it's groupby, wasted my time reading about windowing functions. thanks a lot